# Display Selected row from Gridview using ASP.NET and VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have here the link of tutorial about the Grid view Selection row.

[ASPLINK](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-GridView-Radio-Button-Single-Selection---Select-only-one-RadioButton-from-Column.aspx)

I did the same thing based on the tutorial, I tried to understand the concept and it works. But I want to know how to display the selected row through radio button in every labels that I've created such as; Customer ID, City and Postal

And I've Created also a button to submit or display the selected row. But I don't know how to code it with VB.net

ASP:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
HeaderStyle-BackColor = "green"
AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Arial"
OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging"
Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B"
AllowPaging = "true">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server"
        onclick = "RadioCheck(this);"/>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server"
        Value = '<%#Eval("CustomerID")%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="CustomerID"
    HeaderText="CustomerID"  />
<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="City"
    HeaderText="City" />
<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="PostalCode"
    HeaderText="PostalCode"/>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="Select" runat="server" Text="Select" />
```

VB.NET

```
    Private Sub BindGrid()
        OpenConnection()
        str = "SELECT CustomerID, City, PostalCode FROM Customers"
        adapt = New SqlDataAdapter(str, con)
        adapt.Fill(dt)
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()

        adapt.Dispose()
        con.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetSelectedRecord()
        For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim rb As RadioButton = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).FindControl("RadioButton1"), RadioButton)
            If rb IsNot Nothing Then
                If rb.Checked Then
                    Dim hf As HiddenField = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).FindControl("HiddenField1"), HiddenField)
                    If hf IsNot Nothing Then
                        ViewState("SelectedContact") = hf.Value
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetSelectedRecord()
        For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim rb As RadioButton = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).FindControl("RadioButton1"), RadioButton)
            If rb IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim hf As HiddenField = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).FindControl("HiddenField1"), HiddenField)
                If hf IsNot Nothing And ViewState("SelectedContact") IsNot Nothing Then
                    If hf.Value.Equals(ViewState("SelectedContact").ToString()) Then
                        rb.Checked = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Protected Sub OnPaging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
        GridView1.DataBind()
        SetSelectedRecord()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        GetSelectedRecord()
        BindGrid()  
    End Sub
```

Javascript: The function of this code is to make sure that only one RadioButton is checked

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        function RadioCheck(rb) {
            var gv = document.getElementById("<%=GridView1.ClientID%>");
            var rbs = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");

            var row = rb.parentNode.parentNode;
            for (var i = 0; i < rbs.length; i++) {
                if (rbs[i].type == "radio") {
                    if (rbs[i].checked && rbs[i] != rb) {
                        rbs[i].checked = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
</script>
```

Please Help me Guys!

Thanks in Advanced :)

Comment: Some code would be helpful to see where you're at.

Comment: LEt me understand this, instead of giving "SELECT"  on gridview, you want to use a Radio button, right?

Comment: Through radiobutton sir then I would click the Button named Select in order to display the CustomerID, City and PostalCode from Selected Row